# bundler-audit for insecure source

Tags: rubygems, bundler, audit

I want to use [bundler-audit](https://github.com/rubysec/bundler-audit) for auditing my Gemfile.lock but I have my own gems repository. When I run

```
bundler-audit
```

It always give me this error or notification:

```
Insecure Source URI found: http://gems.repository.cu/
Unpatched versions found!
```

Then, how do I tell to bundler-audit that I want to check from an insecure source ?

Is it possible?

Comment: From the source code it seems it also checks gems from Insecure Sources it just displays a warning on the console that it found an insecure source.

Comment: but it is a red warning !! and also show  `Unpatched versions found!` , what is it?

Comment: The latest version of bundler-audit is not released yet and this is a bug in the old version. It should display "Insecure Source URI found: http://gems.repository.cu/" in yellow and "Vulnerabilities found!" in red. And it means that it checked all your gems and no other problems it has found but it saw the http gemsouce so it displayed this warning.

Comment: what is the latest version? I am using: `bundler-audit (0.3.1)`

Comment: 0.3,1 is the latest version. The version (https://github.com/rubysec/bundler-audit/commit/8a85b9cb256c77d630c98db44c0e4bba02ea2b53) I've mentioned is not released yet.